# Split a sentence by words just as BERT Tokenizer would do?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to localize all the [UNK] tokens of BERT tokenizer on my text. Once I have the position of the UNK token, I need to identify what word it belongs to. For that, I tried to get the position of the word using words_ids() or token_to_words() methods (the result is the same, I think) which give me the id word of this token.

The problem is, for a large text, there are many ways to split the text by words, and the ways I tried don't match with the position I get from token_to_words method. How I can split my text in the same way Bert tokenizer do?

I saw BERT use WordPiece for tokenize in sub-words, but nothing for complete words.

I'm at this point:

```
  tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(texto) # Tokens
  encoding_text = tokenizer(texto) # Esto es de tipo batchEncoding, como una instancia del tokenizer
  tpos = [i for i, element in enumerate(tokenized_text) if element == "[UNK]"]  # Posicion en la lista de tokens

  word_list = texto.split(" ")
  for x in tpos:
    wpos = encoding_text.token_to_word(x) # Posicion en la lista de palabras
    print("La palabra:  ", word_list[wpos], "    contiene un token desconocido: ", tokenizer.tokenize(word_list[wpos]))
```

but it fails because the index "wpos" doesn't fit properly with my word_list.

Comment: It's apparent that you can't match the index of `word_list = texto.split(" ")` that split by space with BERT Tokenizer! Also, you have been found `tpos` and you can get the words from BERT vocab in its tokenizer. why don't you use that?

Comment: What is the exact error that you have? Also what is the version of huggingface ? `token_to_word` gives me an error.

Comment: Pouria: If I use the tpos, I get the token tokenized, which is "[UKN]" but I want to know which letters or words there are behind of it, which ones it didn't recognize and consider Unknowns, that's why I want to map it with th words.

Comment: qmeeus: I don't have any error using token_to_word. If you have, maybe you are not appling the method on a batchencoding object.

Comment: Please give us an example that fails and indicated the expected output. I currently think you are looking for `token_to_chars()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved with `token_to_chars()` method as @cronoik proposed in comments. It gives me the exact position (and it is universal, not like words I used before which depends on how is splited) of any token, even UNK.